# Package catalog to download .xap file in MEF in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-5.0

I am using package catalog to download .xap file on button click event.

```
Package.DownloadPackageAsync(new Uri("Project.xap", UriKind.Relative),
          (args, p) => cat.AddPackage(p))
```

Now my question is that when I click on button, is it every time download "Project.xap" or only one time and after that is uses from cache.

Plz help me.

Comment: @Rumplin I have write this one line on button click and it download project.xap file. but i dont know wether it download project.xap file every time or only one time when i click on button.